# how to get selected value from ionic 4 ion-select

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to get the selected option Value from ion-select
but when I select any value from ion-select I am getting Undefined value since I am new to ionic 4.
I was unable to sort it on my own.

```
  <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Country</ion-label>
              <ion-select formControlName="country" (ionChange)="countryChange($event)" >
                  <ion-select-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.value">{{country.name}}</ion-select-option>
              </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
```

home.page.ts file

```
    countryChange(country : Country) {
        console.log(country.id) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This in the ts file:

```
countryChange($event) {
    console.log($event.target.value) ;
}
```

This will give you the selected value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was stuck in code from 3 days, now the problem is solved

Comment: @AmitNamdeo.Your Welcome. Can you please mark this answer by checking the tick mark?